# Setting all negative values of a tensor to zero (in tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

Here's my problem. I have a tensor X and I want to set all negative values to zero. In numpy, I would do the following `np.maximum(0, X)`. Is there any way to achieve the same effect in tensorflow? I tried `tf.maximum(tf.fill(X.get_shape(), 0.0), X)`, but this throws `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)`.

PS. X is a 1-D tensor of shape (?,).

Answer (score 27):

As it happens, your problem is exactly the same as computing the [rectifier activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), and TensorFlow has a built-in operator, [`tf.nn.relu()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu), that does exactly what you need:

```
X_with_negatives_set_to_zero = tf.nn.relu(X)
```

Comment: That's pretty smart. Another simple solution is `X = tf.cast(X > 0, X.dtype) * X`.

Comment: @lucasdavid Thanks! Your solution helped me with setting all values below a certain threshold to zero. Just changed it to `X = tf.cast(X > threshold, X.dtype) * X`.

Comment: `y = tf.maximum(x, threshold)` works when threshold is an integer or float, now. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use tf.clip_by_value function as follows:

```
t = tf.clip_by_value(t, min_val, max_val)
```

It will clip tensor t in the range [min_val, max_val]. Here you can set min_val to 0 to clip all negative values and set those to 0. More documentation about [clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value).

Comment: what to put in max_val then?

Comment: max_val can be `t.dtype.max`

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to use the cast function [keras documentation](https://keras.io/backend/#cast) (as suggested by @ldavid)

```
X = tf.cast(X > 0, X.dtype) * X
```

Moreover this can be adapted to any threshold level with :

```
X = tf.cast(X > threshold, X.dtype) * X
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution could be this (although it's not the best):

```
class TensorClass(object):
    def __init__(tensor_values):
        self.test_tensor = tf.Variable(tensor_values, name="test_tensor")

test_session = tf.Session()
with test_session.as_default():
    tc = TensorClass([1, -1, 2, -2, 3])
    test_session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    test_tensor_value = test_session.run(tc.test_tensor)
    print(test_tensor_value) # Will print [1, -1, 2, -2, 3]
    new_test_tensor_value = [element * int(element > 0) for element in test_tensor_value]
    test_tensor_value_assign_op = tf.assign(tc.test_tensor, new_test_tensor_value)
    test_session.run(test_tensor_value_assign_op)
    test_tensor_value = test_session.run(tc.test_tensor)
    print(test_tensor_value) # Will print [1 0 2 0 3]
```

While this does what you need, it's not done in tensorflow. We are pulling out a tensorflow variable, changing it, and putting it back again.

For performance critical things, don't use this because it's not very efficient.